# Has a proper version of Bernstein's lectures, written by Karl Rumelhart ever been published as a proper book/article?

Tags: representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, p-adic-number-theory, langlands-program

I'm specifically refering to the set of ntoes as seen here:
[https://people.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/Jerusalem_2010/GradStudentSeminar/p-adic.pdf](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/Jerusalem_2010/GradStudentSeminar/p-adic.pdf)

This set of notes serves as a great introduction to the field, however they are incomplete, contain typos, and, as far as I can tell, do not constitute a proper publication.  None the less, I see this set of notes being cited as a source in peer reviwed articles.  Thus, I can only hope that a proper version of these notes have been published somewhere.
Is this the case, and where can I find them?

If not, why are people allowed to cite this as a reference?

Comment: Which peer reviewed articles has this been cited by? Which journals?

Comment: As one example, Alan Roche's notes in the Ottawa lectures.